# Are the "VK_..." keyCodes methods or objects?

Tags: java, keycode

I want to have a method that would click a certain key

```
public void pressKey ( KeyEvent keyName ) {  // what class must keyName belong to ? 
    this.robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.keyName);
    this.robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.keyName);
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

It should work as a shorcut for example

```
pressKey(VK_ENTER);
```

But I tried to look up those `VK_` codes and still do not know to what class do the keycodes belong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `VK_` values are static fields in the [`KeyEvent` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html).

Here is [a list of all the values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_DEAD_GRAVE).

Comment: Thank You +1. So how should i correct my method so that it works ?

Comment: @AlekseiNikolaevich `pressKey(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);`

Comment: @AlekseiNikolaevich: you have to write your method like `public void pressKey(int keyName)` and then call the parameter with `this.robot.keyPress(keyName)`.

Answer (score 2):

The `VK_` codes are of type `int`.